# как перезаписать значение ключей в объекте JS &

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть два объекта:

```
let obj1 =  {
    "txt": false,
    "log": false,
    "ini": false,
    "com": false
  }

let obj2 =  {
    "1": true,
    "2": false,
    "3": true,
    "4": false
  }
```

Как можно сделать чтоб по порядку перезаписались значения из obj2 в obj1? Тоесть мне нужно чтоб после выполнения функции стало:

```
 let obj1 =  {
    "txt": true,
    "log": false,
    "ini": true,
    "com": false
  }
```

Если не поможете с решением, будьте добры, подскажите где об этом можно почитать.

Comment: Пхоже на то что можно получить массив значений Object.values() обеих обьектов.  Потом поменять значения в массивах и вернуть как-то в обьект... Буду пробовать

Comment: Не во всех браузерах порядок элементов в JSON будет одинаковым. В общем случае сделать такое не получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верить ресурсу [Learn JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/), то если имя свойства – нечисловая строка, то такие ключи всегда перебираются в том же порядке, в каком присваивались.

У вас во втором объекте используется ключ в виде числа, то лучше использоваться массив, или просто начинаться отчет от 1.

```js
let obj1 =  {
  "txt": false,
  "log": false,
  "ini": false,
  "com": false
};

let obj2 =  {
  "1": true,
  "2": false,
  "3": true,
  "4": false
};

function merge(target, obj) {
  let i = 1;

  for(let key in target) {
    target[key] = obj[i++];
  }
}

merge(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1);
```

[В каком порядке перебираются свойства?](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in#v-kakom-poryadke-perebirayutsya-svoystva)